# Laravel 5.x How to obtain the controller name using a route name?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the controller name using a route name.

I have a route ['dashboard'] and I will like to get the controller name to later execute a method on the same controller.

I read the documentation but could find a method or way.

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html

Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: with request I will get the current route, I am in need to pass a route name, not the current one.

Comment: Why getController() did not work for you? https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_getController

Comment: @MuratTutumlu That will work with a current route instance. The questioner wants to pass in the a string route name and get the handler back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an example, this will give you information for the `register` route:

`Route::getRoutes()->getByName('register')->action;`

This will give you an array of all the information you should need:

```
[
     "middleware" => [
       "web",
     ],
     "uses" => "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm",
     "controller" => "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm",
     "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers",
     "prefix" => null,
     "where" => [],
     "as" => "register",
   ]
```

If you're doing this alot, you can add a macro in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function register()
{
    Route::macro('getByName', function($name) {
        return $this->getRoutes()->getByName($name);
    });
}
```

and now you can simply do
`Route::getByName('register')` to get all the route information.

Comment: You nail it, this is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
get_class(\Request::route()->getController());
```

Comment: What if I need all of the controllers? For example I have 5 controllers in my project and I want to get the names of all of those 5?

Comment: @user1477132 That is a question not a comment. You can ask a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.